# Как сервлету получить значение session-timeout из web.xml?

Tags: java, сессия, servlet

В **web.xml** время жизни сессии установлено 15 минут:

```
  ...
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  ...
```

**Как программно  получить значение session-timeout из web.xml для сервлета ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы задать значение, нужно использовать `setMaxInactiveInterval`, где время задаётся в секундах.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(15*60); // 15 минут
```

Для получения значения нужно использовать `getMaxInactiveInterval`, оно покажет вам session-timeout из web.xml, если вы не изменяли session-timeout с помощью метода `setMaxInactiveInterval` до этого.

```
System.out.println(session.getMaxInactiveInterval());
```

Comment: автор спрашивает про получение параметра "15"

Comment: @Etki, я дополнил ответ.